# Defining conditional logic in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `ClientLookupTable` and a `LookupTable` as below.

[image: ![enter image description here]

The `ClientLookupTable` specifies which lookup items are required for a client. 
This is easy to do as I can just switch on and off the `isRequired` flag. 
However, what I need to do is require either `LookupTableId` 19 or both 6 and 20. 
I'm not sure how to go about designing the database tables for this requirement.

The data in `ClientLookupTable` will be consumed by another client application. But we need to define that for a particular client(3), what is required of them is either WID (19) or BOTH SSN or DOB.

Comment: There's not enough information on what you want to do. Please explain with further details and expected results, and provide sample data as code not images.

Comment: Could you add a new column in `ClientLookupTable` that specifies different options and their priority. Perhaps an integer column named `options` so that `19` would be `1`, then `6` and `20` would be `2`.

Comment: @LuisCazares, I added additional info. But basically I just need to be able to define, in the database table whether a client is required to provide all 3 or 1 of the 3. I'm not sure if this would be possible to do at the database level.

Comment: At the table level this is called a **constraint**. However, since you want to turn them "on" and "off"  it is better to handle this in your `insert` and `update` statements.

Comment: @JNevill, that sounds like it could work. I'll try it and see how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: @User123 You bet! I think it's the simplest route to what you want and it scales nicely!

Comment: @ JNevill, based on your suggestion, I added a another table off of ClientLookupTable, RequirementGroupingTable that holds a GroupId, a guid and an FK to ClietnLookUpTable. This way if there is not requirement grouping, nothing is inserted into the new table
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* add a trigger or check constraint to the table.  This would guarantee that the data is meets one of the conditions.  For the constraint, you need to define a user-defined function.

However, I strongly do not recommend this.  The problem with multi-row constraints is that you cannot add one row to the table.  It is not going to meet the constraint.  This can make it hard to insert new rows and update existing ones.

One possibility would be to pivot the the columns:

```
id    clientId    needs_wid    needs_ssn    needsdob
139      3            1            0            0
```

Then a simple `check` constraint works:

```
add constraint chk_ClientLookupTable_required
    check ( (needs_wid = 1) or (needs_ssn = 1 and needsdob = 1) )
```

I'm sure you are putting data in separate rows for flexibility.  Unfortunately, this loses the flexibility.  You could replace the columns with JSON or XML to re-establish the flexibilty.